# Differences between windows and ubunto python scripts

Tags: python, linux, windows

I was having a little problem. My script works fine in Linux Ubuntu

When it came to Windows I fell short. my script uses `import argparse` so I need to pass arguments via cmd but I was getting errors. I figured out the answer while typing this.

**For anyone looking for answers you just do this:**

For me it was something that had to do with toying with archives

```
     python file.py  Archive.zip -c (--compress) test1.txt
```

This action will compress test1.txt in Archive.zip

I feel stupid to think that there is a big difference between command line in Windows and Linux when handling python.

Keep in mind to know where your arguments should be *

I Changed the places between -c and the name of the archive by mistake
and I was typing `python3` instead of `python` for a while like an idiot.

- So the biggest difference is `python3` for Linux and `python` for Windows.
- Is there anything else different between Linux and Windows when handling python scripts?

turned out everything is here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html

and here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/unix.html

Anyone interested check those links to get a better idea there was no need for my question after all :(

Comment: python and python3 are different versions of python, be it on Windows, Linux or whatever. If your program is written in python v.2, use the command python, otherwise use python3. If there is no such version, install it. Also, there are some OS-specific packages that may not work on the system they aren't intended for.

Comment: ok but I think in windows you use py or python for any version installed but if you want precise the version you use you do py -3 for versions 3.x for exemple  but you can't use python3 it used only in linux

Comment: There is no `python3` command for the standard Python 3 installation on Windows. You can create one, if you want, by creating a "python3.exe" symbolic link to python.exe in the installation directory.

Comment: As to the command line, on Windows each program parses its own command line however it wants to. Python uses the C runtime to parse the command line into arguments according to VC++ rules. On Unix the command line is parsed into arguments consistently by the shell, or the parent process in general. Applications don't have a say in the matter.

Comment: forget what I said earlier am using one programme that imports everything and parses commands depending on a list of comditions

Comment: `argparse` uses `sys.argv`, which already has the command line parsed into arguments. It then reparses that list at a higher level. The platform difference is in how and by what rules the command line gets parsed into the `sys.argv` list to begin with. Unix developers take for granted that this is the `char **argv` list from an `exec` call. OTOH, on Windows every process is responsible for processing the raw command line string into arguments by whatever rules it wants. In practice most programs use the C runtime's `argv` from `main` or `wmain`.